# How can you use flexbox method to center div(second child) inside another div (parent), but not let it be affected by (first) child?

Tags: css

In my case, flexbox method works very well for centering the navbar as the navbar has fixed positioning. What I don't want is the other div that's at the same level as the div I am having centered skew the div I want centered; I want it centered to the entire document, not just the area of the parent div that it is allowed.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family:'Smooch Sans';
  font-size:1.2em;
}

.navbar-item {
  float: left;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin:0.5rem;
  border-radius:10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.navbar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
.navbar a.active:hover { background-color:#048f5c;
}
.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
div.navbar-options {
  position:relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div#navbar-left-title {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Smooch+Sans&display=swap');
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="navbar-left-title" style="width:fit-contents;float:left;">The Website Name</div>
    <div class="navbar-options">
      <div class="navbar-item"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#news">News</a></div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#about">About</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is all of the code. Sorry all the styling clogs it up. So I don't want the `div#navbar-left-title` to skew the `div.navbar-options` off the absolute center, in conclusion. Haven't been able to find any solution!
[link to the general idea off of tesla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg8XZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to add `position: absolute` to `#navbar-left-title` as below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Smooch Sans';
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar-item {
  float: left;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.navbar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navbar a.active:hover {
  background-color: #048f5c;
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

div.navbar-options {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div#navbar-left-title {
  color: white;
  width: fit-contents;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Smooch+Sans&display=swap');
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="navbar-left-title">The Website Name</div>
    <div class="navbar-options">
      <div class="navbar-item"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#news">News</a></div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#about">About</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

A more complicated solution would be to set up a grid with three columns such as

```
<navbar>
  <div class="left">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    ...
  </div>
</navbar>
```

and set it up so that `left` and `right` have the same width always, so the `center` element can fill the remaining space.

Comment: Thank you very much! and for such a quick response. I think, for now, since I am newer to  web development in general, I'll use the first method. But I'll reffer to the grid method too, if I'll need it in the future!